# Download issue after app update in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

My app's first update is recently launched when i go to app store and download it. It first download previous version and when i tap **Open** in the app store then it downloads the updated new version. What is this problem why is this happening what factors can be causing this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you deleted previous app from your device?

Comment: Yes. I deleted it first then this happened not only on single app on two of my apps i am facing this problem

Comment: Normally it happens if you have two different versions of same app.

Comment: Two different version of app means? Apple have approved the update and it should have replaced older version.

Comment: means two different version on your device.